# Remove the sizer in a textarea box

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to remove the sizer on the bottom right of a textarea?

Here is my HTML:

```
<textarea class="edit" placeholder="your tagline" style="position: absolute; left: 395px; top: 62px; width: 310px; height: 286px; color: rgb(169, 169, 169); padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;">your tagline</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be do in html easy

```
<textarea name="textinput" draggable="false"></textarea>
```

This works for me. Default value is true for draggable attribute.